# Scheme recursion function

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, r5rs

Hey i've been stuck on the following problem and cant seem to come up with the correct function.

Write a recursive function that, given a positive integer k, computes the product k:
(1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/k)... as k decreases by one.

I cant seem to come up with the correct function i the program usually runs till it has no more memory left. Here is my method:

```
(define (fraction-product k)
  (if (= k 0)
       0
       (* (- 1 (/ 1 (fraction-product (- k 1)))))))
```

thanks for any help in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Do small cases by hand first.

Without trying to code it, hand-calculate what the answer should be for:

- *(fraction-product 1)*
- *(fraction-product 2)*
- *(fraction-product 3)*

You should at least have three concrete examples in hand before you do these kinds of problems: not only does it help to clarify some confusion, but they can serve as sanity test cases when you get to actual code.

Is there a relationship between the answer you hand calculate between *(fraction-product 1)* and *(fraction-product 2)*?  How about between *(fraction-product 2)* and *(fraction-product 3)*?

Do we have to worry about *(fraction-product 0)*?  Check your problem statement.

Don't go straight to code when you see problems like this.  Do small examples by hand first: compute what the answer *should* be.  It will help kickstart your intuition on what the program is really trying to compute, and how to do it mechanically.

If you have time, see a book like [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), which describes a systematic approach on designing these kinds of functions.

Answer (score 0):

What are the arguments of the product? There is only one!
The product is therefore useless, since `(* n) == (* n 1) == n`.
This should tell you immediately that your algorithm doesn't do what you want.

A good strategy to find such bugs is to write all the parameters of function of separate lines…

Also, when `k == 0`, `(fraction-product 0)` returns 0.
Then `(fraction-product 1)` will compute `(/ 1 (fraction-product 0)) == (/ 1 0)` which is probably not what you want to do again…

Actually, it seems that you want to compute something completely different from a product of fractions… rather a recursive fraction (I forgot the name of such things).

Anyway, to do `(1 - 1/2) * (1 - 1/3) * ... * (1 - 1/k)` you could do something like

```
(define (f-p k)
  (define (aux n) (- 1 (/ 1 n)))
  (let loop ((i 2))
    (if (> i k)
      1 ;; base case: multiply by 1, i.e. "do nothing"
      (* (aux i) (loop (+ i 1))))))
```

This can be optimised to use constant stack space, but it isn't the point, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You got wrong the base case: it should state that if `k` is `1`, then return `1` - when you're multiplying recursively you have to make sure that the recursion stops when the number `1` is reached, if you multiply by `0` the result will always be `0`.

The recursive call is also mistaken, notice that you must multiply `(- 1 (/ 1 k))` times the result of the recursion. Try something like this:

```
(define (fraction-product k)
  (if (<= k 1)
      1
      (* (- 1 (/ 1 k))
         (fraction-product (- k 1)))))
```

As suggested in @Axioplase's answer, the same procedure can be written in such a way that it uses constant stack space by using tail recursion - the recursive call is the last thing the procedure executes before returning and is thus in tail position:

```
(define (fraction-product k)
  (let loop ((acc 1)
             (k k))
    (if (<= k 1)
        acc
        (loop (* acc (- 1 (/ 1 k))) (- k 1)))))
```

And just for fun, it's easy to realize that the same procedure can be written as simple as this:

```
(define (fraction-product k)
  (/ 1 k))
```

Comment: There is no need to convert a tail-recursive function to an iterative function: The Lisp interpreter does that automatically.

Comment: @Eyal but anyway you have to write the recursion in such a way that it uses a tail call, the first version of the procedure above _will not_ be automatically transformed to the second one. And the second one is not an iterative function, is a tail-recursion written using a named let.